# What determines the final direction of Sima Zhao's Ex attack?

Tags: dynasty-warriors-7

Sima Zhao's Ex attack causes him to pounce on his opponent and ride him into the ground.  At the end of this action the target ends up being flung outwards.  If I want to follow up for my next combo, I need to know which direction my opponent will be flung.

What determines this direction?

---

PS, here is some fan service:
[image]

Comment: Youtube link is broken.